# Selenium node keeps going down

Tags: java, selenium, connection, nodes, remotewebdriver

I am trying to set up a hub where I can run my tests on my laptop from my desktop using Selenium.

I start the hub using `Java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role hub` and it succeeds.

[hub is Successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODxcK.png)

I go to my laptop and register it as a node using `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.0.3:4444/grid/register/ -port 5566` and it succeeds.

[Node is successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNtj5.png)

However, this is appearing in my hub Command Prompt, grid console, and hub Command Prompt.

[Hub errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZmpK.png), [Grid Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ahBt.png), [Node Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zFwC.png)

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I remember it working in the past but that was months ago. Are there any ports I should forward in the router?

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The error stack trace shown while starting the *Selenium Grid Node* says it all :

[image: Selenium Grid Node error stack trace]

You are trying to start a *Selenium Grid Node* but not a *Selenium Server* . So to start the *Selenium Grid Node* you should use the following command :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.0.3:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

Update :
As you are using both the *Selenium Grid Hub* and the *Selenium Grid Node* both of them from the same *localhost* you can use the following command to start the *Node* as well :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

Comment: Tried as you suggested and still seeing the same errors. Can I add screenshot to the comments?

Comment: Any specific reason to start _Node_ on port 5566 instead of default 5555?

Comment: That was the port I used when I originally learned how to do this. Running with default port has the same issues. This looks a lot like the defect https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3631 however, that defect was long ago and fixed.

Comment: The mentioned issue have no impact with using port _5555_ or _5566_ . Can you update me the _JDK_ version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

As you saied, your hub and node on same machine,

why your hub ip is `192.168.0.3`, but node ip is `192.168.0.13`?  Did you use VM for node?

If Yes, please make sure the host and VM can ping each other to make sure they can access each other.

The error message in screenhost: Hub Errors, told the hub can't access node : 
`can reach the node for 2 tries`

If No, the hub and node IP should be same, it's no way come out two IPs

And the register cmd should user `-role node`, not  `-role webdriver`

Comment: Hub is on PC and node is on laptop. I did manage to get it to work. I needed to allow the node to pass through windows firewall.